# How to get multiple instance details of single process in c#?

Tags: c#

In my desktop triplE application is running. Its process name is "Orig_sysdsner". Here single process is creating but multiple instances are creating where each instance title will be unique. Now i want to get all instances of this process with instance name. How to do it in C#?

Below function i have tried but getting last opened instance details.

```
public static List<string> GetDGDesignEditorRunningInstance()
{
    List<string> runningInstanceList = new List<string>();
    List<Process> processList = Process.GetProcessesByName("Orig_sysdsner").ToList();
    try
    {
        foreach (Process process in processList)
        {
            //string instanceName = process.MainModule.FileName;
            string instanceName = process.MainWindowTitle;
            runningInstanceList.Add(instanceName);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return runningInstanceList;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? You already got all instances. BTW you don't need the call to `.ToList()`, GetProcessesByName returns an array that can be used in a `foreach` loop or LINQ query just like a List

Comment: So you see 3 entries in task manager for Orig_sysdsner? What you have should work, perhaps the issue is how you subsequently use the return value, is runningInstanceList correct when you return it?

Comment: @Arunagiri why are you asking about the *window title* anyway? This can be anything the application wants it to be. It won't help you identify the process or any documents it has opened

Comment: If you see only *one* process running with Task Manager then you can only ever get one instance from Process.GetProcessesByName().  It is not unusual for a process to support only a single instance, large programs like an Office app or a browser work that way.  Or in other words, when you start it again then it asks the first instance to create new window and quits.  There is little you can do with such a process, not obvious from the question what that might be, MainWindowTitle certainly does not help at all.  UI Automation is a way to get a notification when such a window is closed.

Answer (score 1):

A process may not have a window title. If I execute this :

```
var runningInstanceList=Process.GetProcessesByName("Chrome")
                           .Select(proc=>proc.MainWindowTitle)
                           .ToList();
```

I'll get back 16 entries and only one of them will have a MainWindowTitle. Chrome uses *tabs* and background processes that don't show any title.

If I use `MicrosoftEdgeCP` I'll get back 17 strings, all with the same title, `Microsoft Edge`.

BTW you don't need the call to `.ToList()` to iterate over the array returned by `GetProcessByName`. `foreach` works on anything that implements `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`. You can use LINQ to select the items you need so you can get rid of the loop and adding the titles to the result list one by one, eg:

```
var runningInstanceList=Process.GetProcessesByName("Chrome")
                           .Select(proc=>new { proc.Id,
                                               proc.ProcessName,
                                               proc.MainWindowTitle
                                             })
                           .ToList();
```

Will return the unique process ID , the name and window title if it exists.

You can use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and add the `Window Title` to the process list to see what title is reported by each application.