# How to get file names of all opened pdf in Adobe Acrobat Reader using C#

Tags: c#, adobe, acrobat

I have opened multiple pdf files in Adobe Acrobat Reader. Below is the snapshot of task manager.
[image]

I want file names (not complete file path) of all opened pdf files using C#. 
I tried below code, but getting the name of only one file.

```
Process[] acrobats = Process.GetProcessesByName("Acrord32");
foreach (Process p in acrobats)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.MainWindowTitle);
}
```

Please help to find out the solution of this problem.

Comment: Maybe the answer here can help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538407/how-to-get-multiple-instance-details-of-single-process-in-c

Answer (score 0):

If you have complete filepath, why dont you just:(?)

filename = Path.GetFileName(strPath); //myfile.txt

or

filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strPath); //myfile

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.